# VIM Syntax highlighting not functioning

Tags: vim, syntax, raspberry-pi

I am fairly new to vim and trying to get syntax highlighting in place. i made and edited my vimrc file and when i look at that file it is colored. But when i go to my python files they have no highlighting. Any help would be great!

```
L: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Example_vimrc
" Authors: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_on_Freenode
" Description: A minimal, but feature rich, example .vimrc. If you are a
"              newbie, basing your first .vimrc on this file is a good choice.
"              If you're a more advanced user, building your own .vimrc based
"              on this file is still a good idea.

"------------------------------------------------------------
" Features {{{1
"
" These options and commands enable some very useful features in Vim, that
" no user should have to live without.

" Set 'nocompatible' to ward off unexpected things that your distro might
" have made, as well as sanely reset options when re-sourcing .vimrc
set nocompatible

" Attempt to determine the type of a file based on its name and possibly its
" contents. Use this to allow intelligent auto-indenting for each filetype,
" and for plugins that are filetype specific.
filetype indent plugin on

" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax on


"------------------------------------------------------------
" Must have options {{{1
"
" These are highly recommended options.

" Vim with default settings does not allow easy switching between multiple files
" in the same editor window. Users can use multiple split windows or multiple
" tab pages to edit multiple files, but it is still best to enable an option to
" allow easier switching between files.
"
" One such option is the 'hidden' option, which allows you to re-use the same
" window and switch from an unsaved buffer without saving it first. Also allows
" you to keep an undo history for multiple files when re-using the same window
" in this way. Note that using persistent undo also lets you undo in multiple
" files even in the same window, but is less efficient and is actually designed
" for keeping undo history after closing Vim entirely. Vim will complain if you
" try to quit without saving, and swap files will keep you safe if your computer
" crashes.
set hidden

" Note that not everyone likes working this way (with the hidden option).
" Alternatives include using tabs or split windows instead of re-using the same
" window as mentioned above, and/or either of the following options:
" set confirm
" set autowriteall

" Better command-line completion
set wildmenu

" Show partial commands in the last line of the screen
set showcmd

" Highlight searches (use <C-L> to temporarily turn off highlighting; see the
" mapping of <C-L> below)
set hlsearch

" Modelines have historically been a source of security vulnerabilities. As
" such, it may be a good idea to disable them and use the securemodelines
" script, <http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1876>.
" set nomodeline


"------------------------------------------------------------
" Usability options {{{1
"
" These are options that users frequently set in their .vimrc. Some of them
" change Vim's behaviour in ways which deviate from the true Vi way, but
" which are considered to add usability. Which, if any, of these options to
" use is very much a personal preference, but they are harmless.

" Use case insensitive search, except when using capital letters
set ignorecase
set smartcase

" Allow backspacing over autoindent, line breaks and start of insert action
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" When opening a new line and no filetype-specific indenting is enabled, keep
" the same indent as the line you're currently on. Useful for READMEs, etc.
set autoindent

" Stop certain movements from always going to the first character of a line.
" While this behaviour deviates from that of Vi, it does what most users
" coming from other editors would expect.
set nostartofline

" Display the cursor position on the last line of the screen or in the status
" line of a window
set ruler

" Always display the status line, even if only one window is displayed
set laststatus=2

" Instead of failing a command because of unsaved changes, instead raise a
" dialogue asking if you wish to save changed files.
set confirm

" Use visual bell instead of beeping when doing something wrong
set visualbell

" And reset the terminal code for the visual bell. If visualbell is set, and
" this line is also included, vim will neither flash nor beep. If visualbell
" is unset, this does nothing.
set t_vb=

" Enable use of the mouse for all modes
set mouse=a

" Set the command window height to 2 lines, to avoid many cases of having to
" "press <Enter> to continue"
set cmdheight=2

" Display line numbers on the left
set number

" Quickly time out on keycodes, but never time out on mappings
set notimeout ttimeout ttimeoutlen=200

" Use <F11> to toggle between 'paste' and 'nopaste'
set pastetoggle=<F11>


"------------------------------------------------------------
" Indentation options {{{1
"
" Indentation settings according to personal preference.

" Indentation settings for using 2 spaces instead of tabs.
" Do not change 'tabstop' from its default value of 8 with this setup.
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab

" Indentation settings for using hard tabs for indent. Display tabs as
" two characters wide.
"set shiftwidth=2
"set tabstop=2


"------------------------------------------------------------
" Mappings {{{1
"
" Useful mappings

" Map Y to act like D and C, i.e. to yank until EOL, rather than act as yy,
" which is the default
map Y y$

" Map <C-L> (redraw screen) to also turn off search highlighting until the
" next search
nnoremap <C-L> :nohl<CR><C-L>


"------------------------------------------------------------
```

File in in location of :
/home/pi

Comment: Can you post the contents of you vimrc?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fTUpdY0N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, using sudo to launch vim and was referencing the from vimrc

Comment: So basically you put the vimrc in the wrong directory (root's home directory instead of your own)